# Reading Riverpod provider outside of build method - Flutter

Tags: flutter, riverpod, auto-route

Currently I'm working with two types of `refs` for reading a Riverpod provider: `WidgetRef` (inside build method, for rebuilding) and `ProviderRef` (anywhere outside of build method, in places unrelated to widget lifecycles).

I am also using `auto_route` package for routing and have made few route guards. This is my `AppRouter` so far:

```
@AutoRouterConfig()
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {
  AppRouter(this.ref) : super();

  WidgetRef ref;

  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
        AutoRoute(
          page: OnboardingRoute.page,
          guards: [OnboardingGuard(ref)],
          // initial: true,
        ),
        AutoRoute(
          page: AuthRoute.page,
          initial: true,
        ),
        AutoRoute(
          page: HomeRoute.page,
          guards: [AuthGuard(ref)],
        ),
      ];
}
```

My `app.dart`:

```
class App extends ConsumerWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final themeMode = ref.watch(themeRepositoryProvider).requireValue.themeMode;

    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: AppRouter(ref).config(),
      themeMode: themeMode,
      theme: appThemeData,
      darkTheme: appThemeDataDark,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

My `AuthGuard`:

```
class AuthGuard extends AutoRouteGuard {
  AuthGuard(this.ref) : super();

  WidgetRef ref;

  @override
  void onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) async {
    final isLoggedIn = ref.watch(authProvider);

    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      router.push(AuthRoute(initial: AuthPages.login));
    } else {
      resolver.next(true);
    }
  }
}
```

**The possible problem I'm currently facing**: as you can see in the `app.dart`, I'm passing a `WidgetRef` to `AppRouter` through the constructor, which is then forwarded to the guards (`AuthGuard` and `OnboardingGuard`). This is done in order for me to read some provider's values, on top of which I do some conditional navigation in those route guards.

My question is, is it okay if I use `WidgetRef` here, or should I somehow inject `ProviderRef` to the `AppRouter` instead? Do you have any advices/negative feedback on this approach?

Thanks

Comment: Don't initiate the router inside build method! See [the docs](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#generating-routable-pages) in the "Finalize the setup" part.